# Cannot see any created Gradle repository in the JFrog Artifactory OSS admin page

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am trying to install Jfrog's Artifactory server. I have created different Gradle repositories, but I cannot see any of them in the admin panel (Administration->Repositories->Repositories).
When I browse to Application->Artifactory->Artifacts  I can see all my created repos. But from this view I cannot manage this repositories.
I tried the same with Maven repositories and I could see them in the admin panel view.

Is Gradle repositories a Pro feature or am I missing something?

Some info about my test environment:

OS: Windows 10

Artifactory: Open source license 7.18.7 rev 71807900 undefined

I found similar question here, but unfortunately it is unanswered:
[Jfrog artifactory OSS does not show Ivy or Gradle repository in artifactory admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67075356/jfrog-artifactory-oss-does-not-show-ivy-or-gradle-repository-in-artifactory-admi?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same issues.

Finally found them under:

Administration > Repositories > Layouts > Select appropriate layout (my repo package type is Gradle so I choose maven2-default) > scroll to bottom and you will see "Repository Associations" with a list of all repositoires you created.

Now click on a repo you want to manage.